# Elasticsearch Date Range Aggregation and Time Zone

Tags: date, elasticsearch, timezone, aggregation

i try to build a date range aggregation, but i have a problem to add the time zone. 
The Timestamps in the search documents look like: "2015-06-29T00:00:00.000+02:00". It`s yoga-time with the german time zone.

The date histogramm aggregation and date range filter have a setting for the time zone:

For example:

```
"range" : {
   "valid_to" : {
      "from" : "now/d",
      "to" : "now/d+1d",
      "time_zone" : "+02:00"
   }
}
```

But i can not find something similar in the date range aggregation:

```
"valid_to" : {
      "date_range" : {
        "field" : "valid_to",
        "ranges" : [ {
          "key" : "today",
          "from" : "now/d",
          "to" : "now/d+1d"
        }, {
          "key" : "week",
          "from" : "now/d",
          "to" : "now/d+6d"
        }, 
        ... ]
      }
    }
```

Did anyone know a solution to add the time zone to the date range aggregation and not to do it by hand? (for example to subtract the time zone offset)

Answer (score 3):

For all who have the same problem, i use a workaround for the missing time_zone parameter. For now, i don't use the date range aggregation. Instead i use the filters aggregation.

My solution looks like:

```
"valid_to": {
    "filters": {
        "filters": {
            "today": {
                "range": {
                    "valid_to": {
                        "from": "now/d",
                        "to": "now/d",
                        "time_zone": "+02:00",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "week": {
                "range": {
                    "valid_to": {
                        "from": "now/d",
                        "to": "now/d+6d",
                        "time_zone": "+02:00",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This workaround solved my problem in Elasticsearch 2.3. Since Elasticsearch 5 there is a time_zone parameter in the date_range aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no option to provide time-zone in date range aggregation. 
The workaround is to explicitly specify the offset. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10130) regarding the same probably you should chime in there.